# GLKit not working in mac catalyst live streaming using Haishinkit

Tags: glkit

Im using hainshinkit framework for live streaming . I have used Replaykit to share screen on live streaming server.
In iOS and iPad app is working properly but when i run the app in mac Catalyst there is error in GLKit framework and app cant build. I have mac air m1.

Expectation: I want to work app like iOS and iPad in macOS device.

Comment: "there is error"—great! Errors contain useful information. What does it say?